# Cancel a message with the Prism Event Aggregator or any other pattern for intercepting commands?

Tags: c#, prism, messaging, cqrs, eventaggregator

Does anyone know some way to cancel any further broadcasting of a message on the Prism event aggregator?

I'm trying to do some fairly standard command/event messaging - let me explain with a sequence diagram:

[image: Standard command/event messaging architecture]

Now I want to add in validation. It makes sense that the validation should intercept the command, determine whether it is a valid command to apply, and if not cancel its broadcast. In essence this is what I want:
[image: Standard command/event messaging with the possibility of command validation]

Does anyone know how to do something along the lines of

```
public class Validator : ISubscribe<ChangePropertyCommand>
  public void Handle(ChangePropertyCommand cmd) {
    if(IsNotValid(cmd))
     _events.Cancel(cmd);
    else
      ...
  }
}
```

Or is there another better pattern to use?

Comment: Is that ChangedPropertyCancelledEvent event meant to be coming from the ChangePropertyValidator and not the StateChanger?

Comment: Yes sir, if the command is cancelled then the StateChanger never gets to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this isn't possible without a fair bit of work to extend the EventAggregator. Seems to me the easiest way to do this would be to only have your validator handle the event that represents the command. If the command is valid then the validator executes the state changer either direct or by raising a new type of event which the state changer handles. Of course if the command is invalid you instead raise your cancelled event.

Comment: Actually about 15 minutes into this screencast, the presenter made an interesting comment about handling invalid commands (not business rules) - http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/MichaelLehman/PP-Symposium-2010-The-Commmand-Query-Separation-Pattern-Chris-Tavares